# Angular 2 Unit Tests - Resize Window before each unit tests

Tags: angular

I am testing an attribute directive. Most of the functionality of the directive can be tested on small screen sizes. How do I provide a window object and resize it to a particular width and height before executing each test case?

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ TestComponent, NavDirective]
  })
  .createComponent(TestComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should open when trigger button is clicked', () => {
  //write tests to simulate a click on the trigger button 
  //but it is visible only when the screen size is small
});
```

Comment: What you're doing is functional/E2E test, not unit test.